# Azure Data factory - data flow expression date and timestamp conversions

Tags: azure-data-factory, date-format

Using derived column i am adding 3 columns -> 2 columns for date and 1 for timestamp. for the date columns i am passing a string as parameter. for eg: 21-11-2021  and timstamp i am using currenttimestamp fucntion.

i wrote expressions in derived columns to convert them as date and timestamp datatype and also in a  format that target table needs which is dd-MM-yyyy and dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss repectively

For date->

expression used:  toDate($initialdate, 'dd-MM-yyyy')

data preview output:  2021-01-21    --(not in the format i want)

After pipline Debug Run, value in target DB(Azure sql database) column:
2021-01-21T00:00:00   -- in table it shows like this I dont understand why

For Timstamp conversion:

Expression used:

toTimestamp(toString(currentTimestamp(), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'Europe/Amsterdam'), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')

Data preview output: 2021-11-17 19:37:04  -- not in the format i want

After pipline Debug Run, value in target DB(Azure sql database) column:
2021-11-17T19:37:04:932   -in table it shows like this I dont understand why

question 1: I am NOT getting values in the format the target requires ???and it should be only in DATE And Datetime2 dataype respectively so no string conversions

question 2: after debug run i dont know why  after insert the  table values look different from Data preview???

Kinldy let me know if i have written any wrong expressions??

--apologies i am not able post pictures---

Comment: whats the error you are getting? Could you please share

Comment: I think you do not need to convert it into specific formatted string before sinking it into the target column. As long as your `toDate` returns you the correct date field you are likely good to go

Comment: Hi @AllAboutBI

Thanks for the reply . I have rewritten  my question with the steps i have performed, please check.

Comment: Hi @ray Thanks for the reply . I have rewritten my question now with the steps i have performed, please check.

Comment: Hi, in Azure SQL database, by default, date and date time are stored in UTC format. You will have to do appropriate transformation from SQL end.

Comment: @AllAboutBI, thanks. so in sql database it will store is the default format.. 

but in the Datapreview, for the expressions i have written,  i am not seeing output in the format i requried.  is the expression i am using wrong??

Answer (score 0):

1. [toDate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#todate) converts input date string to date with default format as yyyy-[M]M-[d]d. **Accepted formats** are :[ yyyy, yyyy-[M]M, yyyy-[M]M-[d]d, yyyy-[M]M-[d]dT* ].

   Same goes with [toTimestamp()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#totimestamp), the default pattern is yyyy-[M]M-[d]d hh:mm:ss[.f...] when it is used.
2. In `Azure SQL Database` as well the default **date** and **datetime2** formats are in YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss as shown below.

[image]

3. But if your column datatypes are in string (varchar) format, then you can change the output format of `date` and `DateTime` in azure data flow mappings.

[image]

When loaded to Azure SQL database, it is shown as below:

[image]

**Note**: This format results when datatype is varchar

4. If the datatype is the date in the Azure SQL database, you can convert them to the required format using date conversions as

`select id, col1, date1, convert(varchar(10),date1,105) as 'dd-MM-YYYY' from test1`

[image]

5. Azure SQL Database always follows the UTC time zone. Using “AT TIME ZONE” convert it another non-UTC time zone.

`select getdate() as a, getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' as b`

[image]

You can also refer to sys.time_zone_info view to check current UTC offset information.

`select * from sys.time_zone_info`